# Nginx Server Blocks: https, non-www, & non-ssl subdomain

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, 301-redirect

Here's my scenario:

Two sites:

1. `https://example.com`
2. `http://dev.example.com`

Site 1 has a ssl certificate.
Site 2 does not.
(In other words, I don't have a wildcard ssl certificate.)

Via Nginx I'm trying to establish the necessary `www` and `HTTP` redirects.

**Goal for site 1** is to direct

`example.com`, `www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com`

...to

`https://example.com`

**Goal for site 2** is to simply let `http://dev.example.com` direct to itself.

**What I've tried for goal 1**

```
# SSL Redirect
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://filethemes.com$request.com;
}

# WWW Redirect
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com
  ssl_certificate <my-path-here>.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key <my-path-here>.key;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri
}

# Site's Primary Server Block
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /var/www/example.com;
  index index.html;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_certificate <my-path-here>.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key <my-path-here>.key;  
}
```

With the above code, `example.com` goes to 'https://example.com' but that's it. The www redirect is not working. Any ideas as to why?

Also, with a simple server block for site 2 (the subdomain `dev.example.com`) it redirects to `https://example.com`. So it seems that I'm inadvertently redirecting my subdomain to the main domain. Ideas?

I know there are already a slew of Nginx questions and answers out there but I couldn't find any solutions that helped me to get things working as desired.

For such a seemingly simple goal its surprising how challenging this is proving.

I'm grateful for any insight folks can offer.

PS: Yes, my ssl certificate supports www and non-www.

**UPDATE:**
The subdomain issue (site 2 above) is no longer an issue... I failed to re-linked the appropriate file from sites-available to sites-enabled.

Still having the same issues with site 1 not redirecting from `www` - naked, with `http` and with `https`.

**SOLVED(!)**
The problem? No DNS CNAME entry (face palm!).
Many thanks to @BE77Y for helping me find the problem. Also, in case it helps others, here's my current and fully working nginx config, consisting of two server blocks, with one that takes care of all the redirecting to the non-www and https (and uses the NGINX best practices of no re-writes and no if statements):

```
# MAIN SERVER BLOCK
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /var/www/example.com;
  index index.html;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_certificate <my-path-here>.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key <my-path-here>.key;  
}

# REDIRECTS (send everything to non-www https)
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  ssl_certificate <my-path-here>.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key <my-path-here>.key;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**Gotchas (for others who don't usually work with servers):**

- clear cache (or open and close incognito windows) between tests
- make sure you have a CNAME DNS entry (www example.com.)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there from what I can see; I would just configure things slightly differently (based on your described requirements), just to simplify things a bit. One thing I'd note for clarification is that you don't seem to have included a dev.example.com segment in your configuration?

Regardless, here's how I'd improve your current configuration:

```
# Primary block including SSL redirect
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/example.com;
  index index.html;

  ssl_certificate <my-path-here>.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key <my-path-here>.key;

  if ( $scheme = http ){
            rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
            }
 }

# WWW Redirect
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com
  ssl_certificate <my-path-here>.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key <my-path-here>.key;
  rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

To clarify the above: this is a 'cleaner' way of doing things; if someone requests your site at `http://example.com`, they will be redirected to `https://example.com` via the `if` statement, and likewise they will correctly be served the site if they request it via https (which would be an issue with separate statements as you had before). 
If they try to access the site via `http://www.example.com` it will be redirected, or via `https://www.example.com` it will correctly negotiate SSL but still be redirected as above.

As I've noted, you haven't included any dev.example.com related segments in your config file - I assume this is because you have these working already, but if not please feel free to comment on this and I'll be happy to assist in including them with the above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  In your code, for the WWW Redirect, should it not be returning to `https` instead of `http`? If I use http, I get a redirect loop when navigating to `example.com`. When using `https` `example.com` goes to `https://example.com` but www redirecting still isn't working :(

Comment: and yes, as I noted in the update to the question, the subdomain is now working properly.

Comment: There shouldn't be a redirect loop, simply a second redirect to https - although yes, now you point it out it would make more sense to leave that return URL as https; I've updated the above to reflect this change!

Comment: In fact it would also make sense to use the same method to rewrite www. URLs, so I have updated the above to alter the 'return 301' to rewrite instead above (which I think may have been the cause of your issues with your WWW redirect)

Comment: Hmm... that's doesn't work. The WWW redirect still isn't working.

Comment: Aha. We're being a bit silly! We need to add a listen 443 ssl; line in the main segment! *doh!* (updated above)

Comment: If only it were that easy :) I already had that, though I didn't have a `listen 80` line in the main segment. Adding `listen 80` to it doesn't seem to change a thing.

Comment: Well you've piqued my interest enough for me to try emulating this exact setup on one of my servers - and it works perfectly with the above. My only advice then would be to perhaps recreate the above config from scratch once again (and make sure no other configs are conflicting with it or taking precedence?)

Comment: Also worth noting that you should make sure to use an incognito window to test (or clear cache on every config change).

Comment: Yes, thanks for your continued interest/help in this! It's much appreciated. I just realized that I didn't have a cname dns entry registered (facepalm!), so I just registered it and will report back once it's propagated. And yes, the cache clearing bit is supper important... that was getting me for a while yesterday.

Comment: Works! Tried to give an upvote but I don't have enough reputation. For other who may be experiencing similar struggles with this, don't forget to create a CNAME DNS entry! Thanks again, @BE77Y

Comment: What would be the entry for the `dev.example.com` subdomain, how would it get included in the block (I have the CNAME setup already). Also, is it possible to achieve this without using any `IF` statements whatsoever?

Comment: @PKHunter yes, you can use `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;` or similar to avoid using `if` statements, however if I were you I'd look into why I'd want to avoid using them in the first place. Where to place `dev.example.com` in your config completely depends on your own scenario; it may be best to read up on the documentation, the above answer, and then (only if necessary) create your own question here if you still need to.